# How to read a stream in Eclipse CLP?

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

I am new to Eclipse, and I have been trying to read a file stream without success. The code that I normally use for this in SWI-Prolog is this:

```
read_until_stop(File, [L|Lines]) :-
    read_line_to_codes(File, Codes),
    Codes \= end_of_file,
    atom_codes(L, Codes),
    L \= stop,
    !,
    read_until_stop(File, Lines).
read_until_stop(_, []).
```

But `read_line_to_codes` is not available in Eclipse apparently. What is a good alternative for this?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the [Eclipse manual](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/userman/umsroot059.html#toc89) the Eclipse counterpart would be

```
read_line(Stream, String) :-
    read_string(Stream, end_of_line, _Length, String).
```

with the difference that [read_string](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/iochar/read_string-4.html) returns the actual string as opposed to the list of codes, i.e., `atom_codes` is no longer necessary:

```
?- read_string(input, end_of_line, Length, String).
      abcdefghi
      Length = 9
      String = "abcdefghi"
      yes.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think read_line_to_codes/2 can easily be implemented in ECLiPSe, but for efficiency reuse available builtins. You can do with [read_line](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/util/read_line-2.html)/2.

Try to define

```
:- use_module(library(util)).
read_line_to_codes(S, L) :- read_line(S, L).
```

or simply call read_line...